# close the activity after finish

Tags: android

i have question 
in android 
after i click to button to go to updateprofile how can i close  the previous activity
for example

```
x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    updateprofile.class);
            startActivity(updateprofile);


        }
    });
```

which method i can call to close the previous activity can you help me 
thanks

Comment: `close the activity after finish` make sense?

Comment: yes i do not want after the user click the return button  to display all the previous interface

Answer (score 2):

by calling `finish()` in the current activity,  ..

```
x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activity2 = new Intent(yourActivity.this,
                    activity2.class);
            startActivity(activity2);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Comment: there is an error 12-03 12:56:46.422: E/WindowManager(358): Activity com.ksu.sms.UpdateProfile has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f63490 that was originally added here
12-03 12:56:46.422: E/WindowManager(358): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ksu.sms.UpdateProfile has leaked window

Answer (score 0):

```
x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
                Intent activity2 = new Intent(mainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(activity2);
    }
});
```